# Why are various minified JavaScript files missing in backend?

Tags: magento2, javascript, magento2.4, minified-js

On the backend login page and within the backend itself the following files from `https://store.example/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/` are not being found (404): `jquery.min.js`, `js/theme.min.js`, `mage/backend/bootstrap.min.js`, `mage/adminhtml/globals.min.js`, `Magento_Catalog/catalog/product.min.js`, `Magento_Translation/js/mage-translation-dictionary.min.js`, `underscore.min.js`, `mage/backend/tabs.min.js`, and `mage/adminhtml/grid.min.js`.

The `.min.js` files do indeed not exist within `pub/static/adminhtml`, but their `.js` counterparts do. All static files in the frontend are being found.

I tried switching JS minification, version signing and merging on and off, all the time clearing `pub/static` and running `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` with the same result: Frontend works fine, but no `.min.js` files in backend and the backend seems to expect those. Currently `dev/js/{merge_files,enable_js_bundling,minify_files,merge_files}` are all off (`0`).

Disabling 3rd-party modules does not help and there are no customizations in `app/design/adminhtml`. This happens on 2.4.4 and after upgrading to 2.4.4-p2 or 2.4.5-p1.

What could be the cause? Which options could be relevant? Does the backend generally use minified versions or not?

Answer (score 0):

The backend generally does not use minified JS version.

Might be this is caused by your browser's cache. Or some configurations for `minify_files` was enabled in the environment config: `app/etc/config.php` and `app/etc/env.php`.

So, check the config in those files, and run the following commands:

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```

Testing with a private browsing session.